# ViewModel does not populate input fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm

I have a ViewModel that is used for an edit View.  When the data is returned, the ID of the item to be edited does not display on the edit View.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Parcel parcel = _parcelDao.GetParcel(id);

    ParcelEditViewModel viewModel = new ParcelEditViewModel();

    viewModel.id = parcel.id;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Should I be returning something different to the View?

**ViewModel**:

```
public class ParcelEditViewModel
{

    public Parcel parcel { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TrackStatus { get; set; }

    public ParcelEditViewModel()
    {
        parcel = new Parcel();

        TrackStatus = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = "AwaitingCollection",
                Text = "Awaiting Collection"
            },
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = "OutForDelivery",
                Text = "Out For Delivery"
            },
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = "Delivered",
                Text = "Delivered"
            }

    };

    }
    public int ParcelStatus { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
//@model ABC.Data.Parcel
@model Abc.ViewModels.ParcelEditViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Parcel</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.parcel.id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parcel.Forename)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.parcel.Forename)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.parcel.Forename)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parcel.Surname)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.parcel.Surname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.parcel.Surname)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parcel.CompanyName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.parcel.CompanyName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.parcel.CompanyName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parcel.Address1)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.parcel.Address1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.parcel.Address1)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parcel.Address2)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.parcel.Address2)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.parcel.Address2)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parcel.Address3)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.parcel.Address3)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.parcel.Address3)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parcel.Postcode)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.parcel.Postcode)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.parcel.Postcode)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParcelStatus)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.parcel.TrackingStatus, Model.TrackStatus)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParcelStatus)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parcel.TrackingNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.parcel.TrackingNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.parcel.TrackingNumber)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parcel.CustomerId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.parcel.CustomerId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.parcel.CustomerId)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

Comment: Could you post your view too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate **all** of your view model's properties; not just the ID. The `ParcelEditViewModel` has no knowledge of what's in your database.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Parcel parcel = _parcelDao.GetParcel(id);
    ParcelEditViewModel viewModel = new ParcelEditViewModel();
    viewModel.id = parcel.id;

    // Populate other properties! These may not be right.
    viewModel.ProductName = parcel.Title;
    viewModel.RecipientName; = parcel.RecipientName;

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

There are mapping libraries such as [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) that can help to streamline this.

Comment: Would you not do that in your viewModel or another class file? instead of the ActionResult

Comment: Absolutely not - mapping belongs in the controller. If you do it in your view model, you've tied your view to your domain model, which is *bad* and contravenes the core principles of the MVC design pattern. If you want to pull it out into a separate static mapping class or something to keep your controller actions tidy, that would make sense but the call to this should still reside in your controller action.